# How to put a wait in between the execution of two functions in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpagetest

Here is my code, in wpt.runtest function i am hitting some url and getting url in response, now i will use this url in my request function, but i need to wait for sometime as it takes some time before the data is available at the url which is to be used in request module.

```js
wpt.runTest('http://some url ',function(err, data) {
        //console.log("hello -->",err || data);

        data_url = data.data.summaryCSV;
        console.log(data_url);
        console.log('-----------');
        console.log(data_url);
        console.log('-----------');

        request({uri:data_url,method:'GET'}, function (error, response,body)  {
            console.log('----@@@@@@----');
            console.log(response.headers);
            console.log('----@@@@@@----');
            //console.log(response);
            if (error) {
                console.log('got an error' + error);
            }
            //console.log(response);
            //console.log(body);
            var data = body;
            console.log('here is the body' + body);
```

what i want is, there should be a time gap or pause before my request function gets executed, how can i achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do I do if I want a JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above problem can be solved by

- [Using Cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)
- [setTimeout function](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/timers.html)

**Using settimeout**

```
wpt.runTest('http://some url ',function(err, data) {
        //console.log("hello -->",err || data);

        data_url = data.data.summaryCSV;
        console.log(data_url);
        console.log('-----------');
        console.log(data_url);
        console.log('-----------');
        var delay = 5000;
        settimeout(function(){
             request({uri:data_url,method:'GET'}, function (error, response,body){
              // handle error and response
             }
        }, delay);
});
```

**using Cron**

This will be really helpful if you have some extended cases of this particular problem. Ex, you need to keep track of resource at various time, lets say after every hour or day. If you are expecting such cases then considering Cron will be helpful.

Steps of execution with cron:

1. Register a cron using the [cron pattern](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger).
2. Start the cron.
3. When pattern evaluates to true, your supplied function will be executed. Put your implementation (making request for resource using `request` library) in supplied function.

Helper libraries for cron in nodejs are [Lib1](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron), [Lib2](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule).

Examples [lib1](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron), [lib2](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/wiki/Cron-style-Scheduling)